# Insert object into google cloud storage returns 'no such bucket'

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

Im using google-api-php-client.
I´m authenticating with service account and recieving TOKEN ok.
Trying to insert object in Google Cloud Storage, using Google Cloud Storage JSON api.

When trying to INSERT object into BUCKET, returns: **NoSuchBucket-The specified bucket does not exist.** But I can assure that it does exist, as I can see in the web manager console, and already have images I´ve uploaded days ago.

The complete message says:
**Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1beta2/b/{here-goes-my-existing-bucket-name}/o?uploadType=multipart&name=thec36b23baf2778d.jpg: (404)**

I can confirm that the bucket exist, as I get a 200 response with full object info when running GET_BUCKET:

```
object(Google_Service_Storage_Bucket)[182]
  {.......}
  protected 'defaultObjectAclType' => string 'Google_Service_Storage_ObjectAccessControl' (length=42)
  protected 'defaultObjectAclDataType' => string 'array' (length=5)
  public 'etag' => string 'CAI=' (length=4)
  public 'id' => string '{here-goes-my-existing-bucket-name}' (length=42)
  {.......}
  public 'name' => string '{here-goes-my-existing-bucket-name}' (length=42)
  protected 'ownerType' => string 'Google_Service_Storage_BucketOwner' (length=34)
  protected 'ownerDataType' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'selfLink' => string 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/{here-goes-my-existing-bucket-name}' (length=87)
  {.......}
```

Could this be an issue of the API?

Comment: Im have smae issue too, and the bucket already exists and have hundreds of files

Comment: I'm having the same problem since this morning.

Comment: Also getting error in the Cloud console (web interface), return error when trying to create Folder or upload an object. So it seems a general error on the API.

Comment: Guys, we are investigating the issue. Can you please write here your bucket names? And if you don't mind, the user you are authenticating with and the default_project_id in ~/.boto.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reporting this.

We are aware of the issue and our Engineers are working hard to fix this.

Meanwhile, you should be able to use `gsutil` as a temporary workaround.

We apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Are you aware of this issue as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563203/

Comment: Seems to been fixed for me. Read here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gs-announce/NDgeG6zF5tw

Comment: This was a transient issue, which was fixed shortly after by our engineers. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gs-announce/NDgeG6zF5tw