# Google Cloud Storage broken?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am constantly getting today:

```
"The request's content type is not accepted on this URL."
```

for anything I try and anywhere I try it. Logging in to new cloud console and uploading file gives this error, creating folder gives that error, uploading from our software gives this error.

Is Google Cloud Storage down? Any help is appreciated.

PS.
This is not multi-part error problem since I am trying to upload also directly from google cloud console!

Comment: Im having the same error in the cloud console (when uploading) and an error when trying to upload via JSON api. Seems a general issue.

Comment: Same here. XML API and Gsutil seem to work though.

Comment: I'm getting errors today too, but related to "bucket does not exist"...

Comment: I'm having this issue as well.

Comment: Same problem here here, from the JSON API and also from the web console.

Comment: We're currently experiencing an issue with the JSON API's upload paths; the announcement thread is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gs-announce/NDgeG6zF5tw

Comment: Also, this kind of report is unfortunately not suited for Stack Overflow. Please contact us about service issues via the channels mentioned under "Community" on this page: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/resources-support#community

Comment: This question is related to a production issue rather than a API usage, tool usage, or programming.  As such, other methods of contacting google should be employed.

Comment: @Benson, am I correct in saying that if you're not on a silver or higher level of support, there is no other way to contact Google?  Also, isn't [google-cloud-storage] supposed to be a replacement for "the general discussion forum for Google Cloud Storage" on google groups?

Comment: @laslowh We also have a public team alias on that page.  We don't have guaranteed response times because it's not explicitly staffed by a support team, but you can reach out to us that way.  The cloud storage tag is intended to be used instead of the discussion forum for programming questions, but not for operational things.

Comment: @Benson Kind of expensive to pay $150/month to be able to create tickets. It doesn't look easy to contact Google if we have problems, but at least we can still complain in stackoverflow. Which other methods of contacting google do you suggest apart of sending an email to gs-team?

Comment: You may do as you like, and we'll do our best. My point is that the Stack Overflow community doesn't want us to use SO for operational issues, and we respect that. The gs-team alias is the best place to report issues or request features.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a temporary production issue, not programming.